# How to turn a regex to non-greedy

Tags: regex, pcre, non-greedy

How to match any character up to the first occurrence of a pattern in a PCRE regex?

The following regex where I'm trying to turn on the non-greedy mode by adding a question mark after the +:

```
.+?(?=non)
```

applied to "Proin non urna non diam feugiat semper" matches "Proin non urna " instead of the desired output: "Proin ".

Thanks.

Comment: It works, see [your regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/PduwNn/2). You may add `^` at the start.

Comment: The `^` anchor did the trick; thanks!

Comment: Well, no need of the anchor if you use the proper method/function that fetches only the first occurrence.